PHP Fatel Error: Timezone database is corrupt
I have a install Apache/2.4.58  and php 7.4.33 I have chrooted the Apache with mod_env and ChrootDir /var/www in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf and far as I know is here the problem.

When creating the chroot, you need to ensure that all relevant system files are available in chroot directory.
It requires quite detailed knowledge of operating system internals to make the files available there.
I recommend that you take a look at running Apache/PHP in a container instead. Containers are more comprehensive than chroots, and they are easier to operate.
